# Can a circle have a negative radius?

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

I am working on a problem that asks if a given sphere intersects the zx-plane.

The equation of the sphere is $(x-2)^2+(y+6)^2+(z-4)^2=5^2$
[image]

Can someone please explain to me how the sphere does not intersect the zx-plane because the radius of the circle is said to be a positive quantity when in fact there is clearly a negative sign in front of the 11.

Thank you

Comment: Can the sum of squares of real numbers be negative?

Comment: No, so I guess this was a typo in the solution that I found.

Comment: Perhaps the solution meant to say "Since the radius *should be* a positive quantity, we conclude that the sphere does not intersect the $zx$-plane". (Even this is slightly inaccurate, though. A radius of zero would be meaningful, indicating that the sphere meets the plane in a single point.) The fact that the sentence *fragment* "Since the radius is a positive quantity." is punctuated like a sentence makes it easy to believe in the typo theory; someone on the editorial staff wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Thanks Blue, that's what I was thinking

Comment: $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=(-r)^2$ is the same curve as $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$. So not only is it possible for a circle to have a negative radius, all circles already do have a negative radius!

Comment: This is about the radius *squared* -- negative square would imply something like *imaginary* radius, not negative radius. Note that, algebraically, circles with negative radius squared can still have ordinary real centers, which can lead to useless discussions about existence, so you'd better just say "impossible for real radius".

Comment: A more representative title would be: Does $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=-r^2$ define a circle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a proof by contradiction.

You first do the assumption that your sphere intersects the plane. From this you would deduce that $(x-2)^2 + (z-4)^2 = -11$. But this is not possible since the number on the left is non-negative and the one on the right is negative. Hence you deduce that your initial assumption was false: the sphere does not intersect the plane.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a\in\Bbb R$ we have $a^{2}\geq0$ and it follows that $(x-2)^{2}+(z-4)^{2}\geq0$. However since you've shown that $(x-2)^{2}+(z-4)^{2}=-11$ we have a contradiction. Clearly the  radius should be a positive quantity as mentioned by Blue, so the sphere does not intersect the $zx$-plane.

Answer (score 2):

If your sphere intersect the $xz$-plane, then there is a point $[x, y, z]$, which is both a point of the $xz$-plane (i. e. $y = 0$) and a point of your sphere (i. e. it satisfied the equation of the sphere).

But then, consequently, $(x-2)^2 + (z-4)^2$ must be a negative number, which is impossible.

So the assumption that the sphere intersect the $xz$-plane was wrong.

Comment: What if you use complex number plane?

Comment: @Nirvana, your comment is out of context of the question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Use the equations to determine their radius and centers.
The radius of sphere is 5, it's center is at $x=2 , y=-6 , z=4$
The distance from xz plane is to center of sphere is 6, the radius of sphere is 5 , it is 1 unit short of touching the xz plane.